# EntityValue doesn't work

Tags: warning-messages, entity

EntityValue  doesn't work

[image]

I have a Windows 10, and *Wolfram Mathematica* 10.4

I reinstalled *W.M* but there is a same problem

Comment: Works for me (MMA 10.4, Mac OS X 10.11.4)

Comment: Note the error: unable to contact the Knowledgebase server. Check to make sure you have an active internet connection.

Comment: @bills I checked, there is no problem . for instance  CityData[Entity[
  "City", {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}], "Population"] works ...

Answer (score 2):

I changed "Date and time setting" in my PC. then it works, (All Entity-Based object)

[image]

Comment: you have to accept this as an answer or the system will keep bumping it up, because it's viewed as an unanswered question.